# 'convert' tool for transforming jpg to pdf freezes/slows computer

Tags: pdf

I was trying to convert a ser of JPG images into a PDF file

Everybody is very happy with the solution `convert *.jpg output.pdf` but in 2 different computers, and just by simply wanting to transform few images, it crashes my computer.

My RAM quickly starts to swap, fills up and the computer freezes.

Comment: Exactly how many images are your trying to simultaneously convert? Have you considered converting in series instead of parallel?

Comment: How much RAM? Never experienced this myself.

Comment: 4GB, +2GB SWAP, How would i set it in series? to explicitly state all the wildcarded files? ´convert pag1.jpb pag2.jpg pag3.jpg ´ ... ´out.pdf´